# Parse REST API 401 Unauthorized with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest, parse-platform

I've been battling parse.com's REST API for an hour with no success. I keep getting HTTP 401 with response `{"error": "unauthorized"}`.

Here is my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendEmail", function(request, response) {

  var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
  Mailgun.initialize('mg.crawford.works', 'key-c67f7a53cf12b2aabeaade0e50d57e8f');

  Mailgun.sendEmail
  ({
    "to": "sales@crawford.works",
    "from": "website@crawford.works",
    "subject": "Website Form Submission",
    "text": "Name: " + request.params.name + "\nEmail:  "+request.params.email+"\nPhone: "+request.params.phone+"\nMessage: "+request.params.msg
  }, 
  {
    success: function(httpResponse) 
    {
      console.log(httpResponse);
      response.success("success");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) 
    {
      console.error(httpResponse);
      response.error("error");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my client side code (just for form submission):

```
var data = {};

data.name = $("#name").val();

data.email = $("#email").val();

data.msg = $("#message").val();

data.phone = $("#phone").val();
$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: "http://api.parse.com/1/functions/sendEmail",
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  headers: 
  { 
    'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'This is the right key, triple checked',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'Same story here'
  }
})
.done(function (response) {
  if (response.success == 'success') {               
    alert('success');                       
  } else {
    alert('fail');
  }
});
return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
```

I've looked at many parse support fourms like this one (StackOverFlow isn't letting me put more links b/c I'm still noob): https://www.parse.com/questions/401-unauthorized-error-with-parse-rest-api

Appreciate any help you can give,

@acrawly

Comment: I copied your jQuery ajax call and replaced with my Application  and Rest api keys and everything works just fine. Try to execute as simple as possible function like this: `Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Hello world!");
});`

Comment: Using Postman everything was working fine so I moved on from thinking Parse was to blame. I'll post my working code (which I don't see a difference on). I cut and pasted my keys so I'm unsure why that would have made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a cloud function you should https in URL not http but to fetch files, use http

Answer (score 0):

So this code ended up working and I can't figure out why:

```
$.ajax("https://api.parse.com/1/functions/sendEmail", {
                dataType: 'json',
                method:'post',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'sameKey',
                      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'sameKeyAgain'
                },
                success: function(data) { //<-- I thought maybe success vs done was it but 
                     //I changed this out and no diff in the result

                    if(data.result === 'success')
                    {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("error");
                    }

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

EDIT: As @hasen pointed out below, it was because I wasn't using HTTPS.